# extract files which is compiled in make process

Tags: gnu-make, u-boot

u-boot support many platform. and there are files with same file name. it's hard to determine which file is involved in the make process for a certain platform. how could I get all files that be used in make process?

Answer (score 0):

You could:

- first, build u-boot for your target platform,
- then look for all object files that resulted from the compilation process.

For example, if your u-boot main makefile were located in `/opt/u-boot-2019.01`,
the following commands would give you all the object files that were compiled:

```
cd /opt/u-boot-2019.01
find . -name "*.o"
```

You can then correlate the list of files you retrieved with the content of your target board's config file, usually located in the `configs` sub-directory.

In my case, the first object files to be displayed are:

```
./scripts/kconfig/zconf.tab.o
./scripts/kconfig/conf.o
./scripts/dtc/srcpos.o
./scripts/dtc/dtc.o
./scripts/dtc/treesource.o
./scripts/dtc/util.o
./scripts/dtc/fstree.o
./scripts/dtc/checks.o
./scripts/dtc/flattree.o
./scripts/dtc/dtc-parser.tab.o
./scripts/dtc/livetree.o
./scripts/dtc/dtc-lexer.lex.o
./scripts/dtc/data.o
./arch/arm/cpu/built-in.o
./arch/arm/cpu/armv8/built-in.o
./arch/arm/cpu/armv8/cpu-dt.o
./arch/arm/cpu/armv8/cache_v8.o
./arch/arm/cpu/armv8/generic_timer.o
./arch/arm/cpu/armv8/exceptions.o
./arch/arm/cpu/armv8/lowlevel_init.o
./arch/arm/cpu/armv8/fwcall.o
./arch/arm/cpu/armv8/cpu.o
./arch/arm/cpu/armv8/start.o
./arch/arm/cpu/armv8/cache.o
./arch/arm/cpu/armv8/transition.o
./arch/arm/cpu/armv8/tlb.o
./arch/arm/mach-sunxi/built-in.o
./arch/arm/mach-sunxi/clock.o
./arch/arm/mach-sunxi/dram_helpers.o
./arch/arm/mach-sunxi/pinmux.o
./arch/arm/mach-sunxi/prcm.o
./arch/arm/mach-sunxi/board.o
./arch/arm/mach-sunxi/clock_sun6i.o
./arch/arm/mach-sunxi/cpu_info.o
./arch/arm/mach-sunxi/rsb.o
```

For example, the fact that the file  `./arch/arm/mach-sunxi/rsb.o` is in the list means that `./arch/arm/mach-sunxi/rsb.c` was compiled during the build process and contributed to the resulting u-boot image.